# EPS file distorts on export in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, color-spaces

I am an Indesign relative beginner (especially related to complex color correction). I've imported an EPS logo file into the document (it's currently layered over a photo) and in preview mode, it looks completely fine.
[image]

Once I export the image, however, the background colors in the circle completely disappear and the color distorts. 
[image]

I have already tried: 1) changing my export options to print (with convert to destination preserve numbers).
2) Making the document transparency blend space RGB and then also CMYK.

I don't have Illustrator, so if you could please suggest any options I would be super grateful (and if you could please explain it step by step that would be fantastic). I'm so confused!

Comment: Is the logo in the EPS vector or raster? Is it CMYK or RGB?  What format are you exporting the image in?  What is the image for?  Is it for print or the web? Can you perhaps share the original EPS file?

Comment: Thanks for your response Billy! I want the file for export as a web file, and I don't know if the EPS is CMYK or RGB. I've tried using both CMYK and RGB blend space on the Indesign file and the EPS file always shows up distorted. This is my first time using Stack Exchange, how can I share the EPS file?

Comment: This is the file here: <a href=http://www.filedropper.com/iylogo><img src=http://www.filedropper.com/download_button.png width=127 height=145 border=0/></a><br /><div style=font-size:9px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;width:127px;font-color:#44a854;> <a href=http://www.filedropper.com >file storage online</a></div>

Comment: And as a link: http://www.filedropper.com/iylogo

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the original EPS has a Transparency Effect enabled. Saving an EPS with Special Effects do not guarantee results in other applications even though AI and InD are both Adobe apps.

If your final product needs to be a web file, then open the EPS in Photoshop and resave it as an JPG.

If you don't have Photoshop either, you can "get by" with this hack: zoom in on the logo in InDesign (fill your screen), and make a screen capture of the logo. This will give you a 72dpi (but at least 1400 pixels wide) RGB PNG that can be replaced into InDesign.

Comment: Hi jhurley, thank you so much for taking the time to answer this. My problem with saving it as a jpeg in Photoshop is that it automatically makes the background of the EPS image white. I need to have the logo background transparent so I can put it over another image. Would there be anything else I can do other than screen capture to work around this?

Comment: I've got lots of ideas. Try this. (1) Place the EPS on a blank InD page. (2) Export that page as a PNG file format. (3) The Export PNG dialog box should offer you a Transparent Background option - turn that on. If the EPS was saved with Transparency Enabled -- your Export as PNG should give you a new transparent logo. Place this new PNG in your doc.

Comment: Or just use this instead http://www.filedropper.com/iy-logo

Comment: The print-screen trick is a good one in a pinch: 1400px is good enough for (1400/300) about 4 inches in print. When doing random "event ad book" ads, this saves a lot of time when the ad buyer sends bad art: go to the website and look for PDFs etc in their press release section.